# Node,js globally on windows 10

Tags: node.js, wamp

So I have installed Node.js at `C:\Program Files\nodejs` but i want to use the npm command in a new project that is at this directory `C:\wamp\www\`.. in my command prompt a project in the `C:\wamp\www\` i get the npm is not a recognised command, but in the another project that is in dir `C:\Users\{{me}}\Proj\` is working fine.. how do i make npm command become recognisable in my wamp\www\ directory??

OR maybe the question should be how do i move my wamp program to my users\ directory without losing any configurations that i have made to it??

Comment: The directory you are in should not affect whether you should issue a command or not, unless the current directory is in your path and npm in a program or batch file in `C:\Users\{{me}}\Proj`.  When you CAN run npm, can you type 'where npm' and report what it shows?  Also `echo %PATH%` or `echo $PATH` if you are running git bash?

Comment: Add path to nodejs  bin folder (hence C:\Program Files\nodejs) into PATH system variable http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them
If you need to move to another folder, then just move package.js file and use `npm install`.

Comment: I restarted my PC and it worked, not sure why

Comment: thanks for the help tho, i should have restarted my PC after installing Node

Comment: Ah, you might have just had to close your console window and open another for the new PATH to be used.  I'm betting the console window where it worked was opened after installing node and a different window was used that didn't work was opened before installing node.  That's the situation that has happened to me before when a command wouldn't work.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat that´s exactly it! haha